# Settext of EditText from another class gives nullpointer

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have extended Dialog to create a popup with a edittext. My plan is to use this popup in a few places within my code. I want to set the edittext when the popup is opened from the class it is opening

Trouble I am having is the settext method gives a nullpointer

```
public class RoundCommentDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context;

    private String roundCommentText;    
    private EditText roundCommentEditText;

    private Button postiveButton;
    private Button negativeButton;

    public RoundCommentDialog(Context context) { 
        super(context); 
    } 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_round_comment_dialog);

        postiveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_positive_button); 
        postiveButton.setOnClickListener (this);
        negativeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_negative_button); 
        negativeButton.setOnClickListener (this);

        roundCommentEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_text);

    }

    public void setRoundCommentText(String roundCommentText) {
        this.roundCommentText = roundCommentText;
    }

    public String getRoundCommentText() {
        return roundCommentEditText.getText().toString();
    }

    public void updateCommentEditField() {

        roundCommentEditText.setText("TEST");
    }

    public Dialog getDialog() {
        updateCommentEditField();
        return this;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.dialog_positive_button:

            setRoundCommentText(roundCommentText);

            dismiss();
            break;
        case R.id.dialog_negative_button:
            cancel();
            break;
        }

    }


}
```

from the class I am calling it from I create new version of the class and then call the setRoundComment(test) method and then the show method. this gives a nullpointer

Thanks for your time

**EDITTED**

Baisiclly I am calling the class above from the main class

```
RoundCommentDialog myDialog = new RoundCommentDialog(this);
```

Then I am doing the following on a Button Listenerer

```
myDialog.setRoundCommentText(roundComentText);
myDialog.getDialog().show();
```

When Errors it is erroring when I call the GetDialog() and within the dialog class it was erroring on the following line

```
roundCommentEditText.setText("TEST");
```

Comment: This is an activity file. Can you describe more what exactly you are doing? Do you have a helper class which accepts TextView ?

Comment: Can you please upload the stacktrace. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also post relevant snippets from the calling activities? Are you using the prepareDialog mechanism?

Comment: updated question with how I am calling the dialog class

Comment: Clean your project to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: not help, still gives a nullpointer when settext th edittet field

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
private String roundCommentText;
```

to

```
public String roundCommentText;
```

I'm no expert with strings but that's what I would try first

Comment: its not erroring on the string field but on the edittext field